# How to debug bitcoin core in "real time"

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, c++, debugging

I am new to bitcoin core and C++

I downloaded already the project from: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin
and run "makefile" command. 
Now I can make all transaction against the blockchain.

I want to have the option to run "getnewaddress" in the command line
and it will stop in a break point in the source code.
but i cann't run the commands "bitcoind" and "getnewaddress", without first building the project.

How can I debug this project?

Comment: In order to debug, you need debug symbols. You can only generate them if you build the source code on your machine with the debug flag on.

Comment: @CinCout how to build the project with the debug flag on ? Is this something I need to change in the code or in the terminal with the "make" command? thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/developer-notes.md#compiling-for-debugging

Answer (score 2):

There is no "makefile" command.

If you don't build the project, there is no way for you to debug it. The released binaries do not contain any debugging symbols so it will be very difficult for you to set breakpoints and see what is going on. So in order to do that, you will need to build the project from the source code that you downloaded. There are instructions for how to do this in the docs folder of the downloaded source code.